# declaring same variable twice in c

Tags: c, scope, initialization, declaration, undefined-behavior

I was just playing around with for loop and wrote below code. When I wrote the second printf statement, compiler asked me to declare the c variable again and when i declared it again i run the code and
got the answer of c + 4 as 20. The for loop works correctly. Why is the c + 4 expression is producing the output 20?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  for(int c =1; c <= 10; ++c)
  {
    printf("%d\n",c);
  }
    
  int c;
  printf("%d ",c+4);
    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: These are different variables with different scope. Printing the second one is UB though, as it is not initialized.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Look at the scope of the first `c`. It is not visible after the loop. You are not using the same variable but a different one that by accident is named identically.

Comment: And because it’s not initialized, you’re getting a “random” value from the stack.

Comment: Why did you add `int c;` in the first place? Did your compiler complain about unknown variable `c` if you don't put that line there? That is the major hint, that the `c` from the loop is not related to that other `c` at all and you cannot expect to have the same value or anything else.

Comment: Just for the case that you still see the result you expected: It's pretty likely (but not at all guaranteed!) that the compiler reuses the memory of the first `c` (that left scope already and ceased to exist) for the second one. The memory, as not being initialised, contains a value reflecting what has been written to the underlying bytes latestly – which, in given scenario (memory reuse!), would be the last value of first `c`. Still it needs to be considered garbage and using the uninitialised value *remains undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two have two separate variables named `c`, each of which resides at a different **scope**.

The scope of the `c` declared in the `for` loop is the `for` statement itself and its body.  This hides the `c` declared at the scope of the `main` function, or it would if the latter were declared before the loop.

Also, the `c` declared in the scope of `main` is uninitialized, and you attempt to read its value.  The value of an uninitialized variable is **indeterminate**, and reading such a value when the variable in question hasn't had its address taken triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As for why you're getting the value 20, that's part of undefined behavior.  There's no guarantee that you'll get any particular value, or even that you'll read the same value twice.

Comment: Re “This masks the `c` declared at the scope of the `main` function”: There is no `c` declared in `main` at that point, and where a `c` is declared in `main`, the `c` inside the `for` is out of scope. There is no overlap in their scopes at all. And we do not need any more words invented for this; the C standard uses “hide,” and people already needlessly use “shadow”; we do not need “mask” too, particularly since “masking” means something else (as in bit masks).

Comment: Re “indeterminate, and reading such a value triggers undefined behavior”: No, it does not. Using `c` does have undefined behavior but not because its value is indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

The program has undefined behavior because the variable `c` in this code snippet was not initialized and has an indeterminate value

```
int c;
printf("%d ",c+4);
```

From the C Standard (J.2 Undefined behavior)

> 1 The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> — The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while
> it is indeterminate

Pay attention to that variables with automatic storage duration (declared in a block scope) are not initialized implicitly as variables with the static storage duration that zero initialized if they have arithmetic types.

If you would write for example

```
static int c;
printf("%d ",c+4);
```

then the output will be `4`.

Comment: @Deepak You can't expect _anything_ since the program has undefined behavior. What you've observed in your program is just a "happening". You can't rely on it. On that topic: Avoid _undefined behavior_ like the plague!

Comment: @Deepak If the variable has static storage duration then it is zero initialized independent on whether it has the type int or, for example, double.  Of course to output a variable of the type double you need to use the format string :%f" instead of "%d".

Comment: J.2 is a non-normative supplement and incorrectly states the rules of the normative text in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different variables there, despite both of them being named `c`, they actually are different things.

The first of them is the one you declared in the for loop, which will no longer be accessible once you exit the loop.

When you declare the second variable after the loop, as you are not initializing it, it will have an indeterminate value.

If you want to use the `c` variable in the loop after exiting it, what you should do is declare it before the loop:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int c;
  for(c =1; c <= 10; ++c)
  {
    printf("%d\n",c);
  }
  
  printf("%d ",c+4);
    
  return 0;
}
```